# (1/1) ErrorException ReflectionFunction::__construct() ex

Tags: laravel

the problem

(1/1) ErrorException
ReflectionFunction::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

```
code

****Route****
-------
   <?PHP
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
  use App\Http\Controllers\usercontroller;
   Route::get('/register', [usercontroller::class, 'register']);

****controller****
--------
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


   class usercontroller extends Controller{

    public function register(){
        return View('register');
    }}
```

Comment: One of your route declaration is invalid, please provide the full version of your `web.php` (route file)

Comment: Try the older notation of Route declaration `Route::get('/register', 'App\Http\Controllers\usercontroller@register');`

Comment: thanks @SahandMoghadam

Route::get('/register', 'usercontroller@register');

this is work

Comment: @AhmedSharif great. so i post it as the right answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the older notation of Route declaration
`Route::get('/register', 'App\Http\Controllers\usercontroller@register')`;